# Should I get 2-3 year old book on Core Animation?

Tags: iphone, core-animation

I'm wondering whether 
a) to buy from Amazon "Core Animation: Simplified Animation Techniques for Mac and iPhone Development", Marcus Zarra (Author), Matt Long" for $34 new, or 
b) assume that iPhone 5 or Xcode 6 or something will happen in the next month or two (hint: WWDC) that may suggest I should postpone and get a book from 2012 instead of Dec2009.

What are your thoughts and/or guesses?

Comment: Please have a look at [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq): "**What kind of questions should I _not_ ask here?** You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face." When you say "What are your thoughts and/or guesses?" that doesn't seem like an practical answerable question, does it?

Comment: None of us can predict the future in regards to Apple APIs. That said, the fundamentals of Core Animation have not changed much since it was first introduced. Learning the basics from any good book or tutorial won't hurt you if new classes or methods are introduced in the future. This is the same for much of the Cocoa and Cocoa Touch API, so I wouldn't avoid older guides simply because some enhancements have been made over time. Marcus and Matt's book is still a valuable resource today.

Comment: This is an "actual problems that I face," whether to spend $30 or not, or possibly waste my time (like on learning memory allocation, only to have it solved by Xcode 5 on ARC - automated reference counting).

Comment: @user945869 - The wording David pointed to might not be appropriate in this case, but we've found that book recommendations and asking for opinions on them doesn't work well on this site and often leads to arguments and unstructured discussion. I might add that time spent learning manual reference counting is not at all wasted when moving to ARC, because it gives you an appreciation of what goes on under the hood and helps you to avoid the few memory issues you could run into with ARC. Learning older techniques has rarely hurt me when presented with newer additions to the Cocoa frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer you to follow the [Core Animation Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) because Apple will be updating it every month. No need to go to 2009 or wait for 3 or 4 months if you read and understand everything and i can recommend you the [Core Animation CookBook](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_Cookbook/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005406) also for the better reference and for referring all the animation types, i prefer [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Animation_Types_Timing/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006166) and if you want to play with images , check [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185) and if you are interested in Quartz 2 Dimensional and 3 Dimensional, check [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066)

Comment: Thanks -- it's good to know that the Apple stuff is current and I did not know about the "Cookbook" for core animation.  Thank you.